# Stack implementation error Leetcode Question 20

Tags: python, list, stack

The leetcode question is :

Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.

An input string is valid if:

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

My code:

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
    
    mapper = {')':'(',
             ']':'[',
             '}':'{'}
    
    stack = []
    top_element = -1
    
    if not s:
        return False
    
    for char in s:
        
        
        if char in mapper and top_element == -1:
            return False
        
        if char in mapper and mapper[char] == top_element:
            stack.pop()
        
        else:
            stack.append(char)
            top_element = stack[-1]
        
        
    return not stack
```

The logic works for '()' input but not for '{[]}'. I think the error is in the `if-else` condition

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The logic and your code is good, you just need to update topelement after the pop.(Change this:

```
if char in mapper and mapper[char] == top_element:
            stack.pop()
        
        else:
            stack.append(char)
            top_element = stack[-1] if len(stack)>0 else None
```

To this (with one more line the commented one):

```
if char in mapper and mapper[char] == top_element:
            stack.pop()
            top_element = stack[-1] #additional line
        
        else:
            stack.append(char)
            top_element = stack[-1]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution it definitely helps. I got one question though, what would be the difference if I did not put top_element =  stack[-1] after pop and modified top_element = stack[-1] from else condition and putting it right out.

Comment: Your code will probably not work, as topelement must be updated after the pop

Answer (score 0):

There are several things:

```py
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
                ^^^^
```

1. Does this function need to be non-static?

```py
    mapper = {')':'(',
             ']':'[',
             '}':'{'}
    
    stack = []
    top_element = -1
    
    if not s:
        return False
    
    for char in s:
        
        
        if char in mapper and top_element == -1:
            return False
        
        if char in mapper and mapper[char] == top_element:
            stack.pop()
            # Change top element
            top_element = stack[-1] if stack else -1
```

2. You need to change `top_element` after `pop`.
3. What if parenthesis is closing, but it doesn't match with `top_element`?

```py
        elif char in mapper and mapper[char] != top_element:
            return False

        else:
            stack.append(char)
            top_element = stack[-1]
        
    return not stack
```

Also you could check if `s` contains other symbols than parenthesis, just in case.

Comment: If parenthesis is closing and it doesn't match, it will return False after the loop ends, as stack will not be empty

Comment: @IoaTzimas ok, got it. Anyway that check makes function return faster in some cases

Answer (score 0):

```
var isValid = function(s) {
    const stack = [];
    const brackets = {
      '{':'}',
      '[':']',
      '(':')'
    }
    const closing = Object.values(brackets);

    for (let ch of s) {
        if (brackets[ch]) {
            stack.push(brackets[ch]);
        } else if (ch == stack.at(-1)) {
            stack.pop()
        } else if (closing.includes(ch)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return !stack.length;
};

console.log(isValid("{([])}")); // true
console.log(isValid("]")); // false
```

Try this Code using JavaScript format at Leetcode you will passed..

Answer (score -1):

- You're in the right path.
- We can just simply add a sentinel value to the stack at initialization.
- This'd pass through:

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, base_string):
        memo = {')': '(', '}': '{', ']': '['}
        stack = [0]
        for character in base_string:
            if character in memo:
                if stack.pop() != memo[character]:
                    return False
            else:
                stack.append(character)
        return stack == [0]
```